# Laravel - how to get profile_picture from another table where the auth username matches?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Im trying to match the Auth user's username with the username in another table and grab they're profile picture in laravel I keep getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `profile_picture` from `profiles` where `user` = username limit 1)
```

This is my query

```
$profile_picture = DB::table('profiles')->where( Auth::user()->username, 'username')->pluck('profile_picture');
```

My table structure is:

> profiles - id | username | profile_picture
>
> users - id | username | email | password | confirmation_code

Comment: You should have a `user_id` column in your `profiles` table, and use that as the foreign key rather than `username`.

Comment: @StuartWagner why? If username is unique and indexed?

Comment: @Steve Foreign keys should point to the primary key of the foreign table. I doubt `username` is OP's primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your where clause should be other way around

```
where( Auth::user()->username, 'username') --> wrong
```

try this

```
$profile_picture = DB::table('profiles')->where('username', Auth::user()->username)->pluck('profile_picture');
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks alot! 

cant believe I missed that. 
$profile_picture = DB::table('profiles')->where('username', Auth::user()->username)->pluck('profile_picture');

Worked like a charm.

Comment: @kevinabraham - `pluck` returns an array. To get the value directly, call `value` instead. (unless you're on an old version of Laravel)

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I'm using laravel 4.2. Using `value` results in an error
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::value()`
That's why I used `pluck`.

Answer (score 0):

$profile_picture = DB::table('profiles')->where('username','=',Auth::user()->username)->get;